# Setting a input value other than having the user put an input

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to set a default value to be sent in the server.

I have a disable text box so if I choose 2nd the 2nd semester will appear in the text field then submit the 2nd semester which appear in the text field in the server and into the database but every time I try to echo out the value, I can't seem to find a value being sent please help

```
<div class = "form-group">

            <?php
            if (isset($_POST['semester'])){
                $semester = $_POST['sem'];
                if ($semester == 1){
                  ?>
                 <input type="text" name="<?php echo $semester?>" value="1st Semester"  disabled>
                  <?php  
                }
                else {
                    ?>
                    <input type="text" name="<?php echo $semester; ?>" value="2nd Semester"  disabled>
                    <?php
                }
            }
            ?>
            <div>
```

this is what I keep on trying just to find out if this textbox return any value if the input is set

```
if(isset($_POST['save11'])){
                $sem = ['1']; //this is the value sent from the $semester
                echo $sem;
            }
```

Comment: what are $_POST['save11'],$_POST['sem'] and $_POST['semester'] ?  Also $sem = ['1'] is an array with a single value in, you can't echo this.  you need to echo $sem[0] to access the value.

Answer (score 0):

The input text will not be sent to the server because it is disabled. If you want to send it with the input form, but not allow the user to change it, read up on [input type hidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden).

> A control that is not displayed but whose value is submitted to the server

All that remains is to find some way to *display* the semester to the user, if that is necessary.